# How do I make a function that accepts an anonymous function using 'do' keyword syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, higher-order-functions

When using `array.each` you can specify the function in two forms:

**Curly Braces:**

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each { |x| puts x * x }
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

**'do' Syntax:**

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each do |x|
    puts (x * x)
end
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

**Question:**
How can I replicate the 'do' syntax style with my own custom function? The closest to the curly brace style I can get is:

**What I've tried:**

```
def PutWith2Arg(proc)
    puts proc.call(2)
end

PutWith2Arg(Proc.new { |x| x + 100 })
```

Output:

```
102
=> nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `do |foo| … end` and `{ |foo| … }` syntaxes are equivalent. These are 'blocks' in Ruby, and any method can get them. To call them you need to either:

```
def my_method               # No need to declare that the method will get a block
  yield(42) if block_given? # Pass 42 to the block, if supplied
end

my_method do |n|
  puts "#{n} times 2 equals #{n*2}"
end
#=> "42 times 2 equals 84"

my_method{ |n| puts "#{n} times 2 equals #{n*2}" }
#=> "42 times 2 equals 84"

my_method # does nothing because no block was passed
```

or, for more sophisticated uses:

```
def my_method( &blk ) # convert the passed block to a Proc named blk
  blk.call( 42 ) if blk
end

# Same results when you call my_method, with or without a block
```

The latter style is useful when you need to pass the block on to another method. If you have a Proc or Lambda referenced by a variable, you can pass it to a method as the block for that method using the `&` syntax:

```
def my_method( &blk )   # convert the passed block to a Proc named blk
  [1,2,3].each( &blk )  # invoke 'each' using the same block passed to me
end
my_method{ |x| p x=>x**2 }
#=> {1=>1}
#=> {2=>4}
#=> {3=>9}
```

For more details, [this webpage](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) is fairly instructive.